# read single character java

Tags: java, io, character

why cant i read this single character?

```
char c = 'Y';
    while(c == 'y' || c == 'Y'){
        //stuff happens..
    }
    c = (char)System.in.read();   <----error
```

I get a compilation error that says "Unhandled exception type IOException"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options to solve this:

1. Handle the exception using a try-catch statement as shown below:

   ```
   char c = 'Y';
   while(c == 'y' || c == 'Y'){
       //stuff happens..
   }
   try {

       c = (char)System.in.read();

   } catch (IOException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();//or however you choose to handle this
   }
   ```

Below the package statement in class (if any), add an import statement like:

```
        import java.io.IOException;
```

2.
Add a throws clause after the function indicating that the funcion may throw a checked exception. In this case you may want to handle the exception in the calling function.

Example: Suppose function sample () calls test()

```
public static void test() throws IOException {

    char c = 'Y';
    while(c == 'y' || c == 'Y'){
        //stuff happens..
    }
    c = (char)System.in.read();

}
```

Below the package statement in class (if any), add an import statement like:

```
        import java.io.IOException;
```

In case 2 you may handle the exception in sample() else the exception (if occurred) will propagate upwards until it is handled.

Answer (score 3):

wrap code in `try/catch` block (or) define `throws` `IOException` in method signature. All checked exceptions should be either catch or throws exceptions.

Example:

```
 try
    {
      c = (char)System.in.read();  
    }catch(IOException ioe)
    {
   //Your catch logic
    }
```

Comment: "IOException cannot be resolved to a type" when I add throws IOException

Comment: add import statement java.io.IOException .

Comment: Click Ctrl + Shift + O to import whatever needs to be imported.